# confusion when converting unix timestamp to timestamp with timezone

Tags: postgresql

I have a unix timestamp in seconds and want to convert it to a timestamp with timezone in postgres.

My confusion originates from the fact that the following does not *add* but *removes* the time zone:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1632610656) at time zone 'Europe/Berlin'

=> "2021-09-26 00:57:36"
```

If I understand it correctly `to_timestamp` creates a timestamp **with** time zone and given [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT-TABLE) the `at time zone 'Europe/Berlin` would then **remove** the time zone? (this feels so strange to me?!).

---

If I now want to get the timestamp with time zone in `Europe/Berlin`, is it correct that I need to do the following?

**1. Option**

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1632610656) at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Europe/Berlin'
=> "2021-09-25 20:57:36+00"
```

and **NOT**

**2. Option**

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1632610656) at time zone 'Europe/Berlin' at time zone 'Europe/Berlin'
=> "2021-09-25 22:57:36+00"
```

They obviously have different results. The first one is the correct one, right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "removes the time zone". `SELECT to_timestamp(1632610656) at time zone 'Europe/Berlin'` shows you what the time was in Berlin when there was 1632610656 in the server time zone.

Comment: by "removes the time zone" I mean that the result has type "without time zone". What do you mean by server time zone? I have no guarantees about any server configuration, but just know that the number is a unix utc timestamp.

Comment: "With time zone" really means "with automatic time zone conversion".  Consider the absurdity of saying "First convert this to Europe/Berlin, but then convert it to my session timezone before sending me the result".  It only makes sense to convert a timestamp to some other timezone if you then stop monkeying around with it.  The way you get it to stop monkeying around with it, is to make the result be of type plain timestamp (e.g. without automatic timezone conversion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different from what your intuition would tell you, a `timestamp with time zone` does not have a certain time zone associated. Rather, it is an “absolute timestamp”.

If you want a `timestamp with time zone` to be displayed in a certain time zone, you have to set the `timezone` parameter in your database session:

```
SET timezone = 'Europe/Berlin';

SELECT to_timestamp(1632610656);
```

If you want a `timestamp without time zone` that shows what a Berlin clock would show at that time, use `AT TIME ZONE`:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1632610656) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin';
```

Comment: I think part of my confusion was that it is possible to save a `timestamp` in a `timestampz` column.